# Invoke Lambda function from SNS with parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-lambda, autoscaling, aws-opsworks

I have an ASG and want to send new EC2's id to a Lambda function using SNS, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this example [Invoking AWS Lambda functions via Amazon SNS](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1VE917Z8J4UDY/Invoking-AWS-Lambda-functions-via-Amazon-SNS)

> When a message is published to an SNS topic that has a Lambda function
>   subscribed to it, the Lambda function is invoked with the payload of
>   the published message.  The Lambda function receives this message
>   payload as an input parameter and can use information contained in the
>   payload to manipulate it, publish it to another set of SNS topics, or
>   send the message to other AWS services.

The example also discusses how to extract the payload. Your EC2 instance id(s) will be part of SNS payload.